# Saving a file to a specific location on WP8 device

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone 8 development. Would like to know if there is a way to store a file received to a particular location on device. It could be using an API, through ActiveSync or MDM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 doesn't allow for free-for-all direct access to the user's hard-drive to read or write files. You'll have to use usecase specific APIs depending on the type of media you're trying to store. I've answered a similar question in the past regarding WP8's read-write access for known file types @ [Windows Phone 8: Media file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467701/windows-phone-8-media-file-access/13473349#13473349)

A few highlights:

1. Your app can use IsoStore to read & write files only accessable to your app. See [IsolatedStorageFile](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---File-manipulations) API or ApplicationData.Current.[LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) API for that.
2. You can store pictures using [MediaLibrary.SavePicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx) or MediaLibrary.SavePictureToCameraRoll methods.
3. You can store songs using [MediaLibraty.SaveSong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385834/api-to-add-playlists-in-zune) method.
4. Other then those APIs I'm not familiar with any other file write APIs to the OS from the top of my head. You can probably use a remote server, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Justin. Could you please elaborate on the line: "You can probably use a remote server"?

Comment: Also, Can we store a file(other than media files) to the Office hub programmatically?

Comment: I meant to say that in addition to storing files only your app can see in IsoStore, you can probably store them in a remote server only your app can see.

Comment: RE: office hub. Please read the attached link to my previous post under "documents".

Comment: Yes! I saw your post in which you have mentioned "Users can then choose to save that copy in the Office Hub". Would like to know, if an app can do it or is it totally up to the user?

Comment: As I said, apps can't read or write documents. Your app can launch a single read-only file in office apps and the user may choose to save it locally.