# WP8 - Saving datas. Single file or database?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am currently developing a Windows Phone 8 app and I am in the need of saving some data, around 50 entries, so that it's still there when the user uses my app again.

What should I use? A "file" or a local DB? I am quite confused even if I spent some researches on the subject.

Thanks in advance!

p.s. I am coding in C# :)

Comment: It is an opinion, but 50 entries seems to be a small amount of data, not worth the hassle of a database.

Comment: How can I actually use a file to store them? :( I couldn't figure it out at all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252673/saving-a-file-to-a-specific-location-on-wp8-device  and also http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpapps/how-does-wp8-storage-work/ea611d18-48f0-437e-b5ed-7ae52eeb98dc

Comment: My DLL Makes doing exactly what you are doing ezzy peezzy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with some of the comments. 50 entries isn't too large and may be better handled by a file. Try using the built in IsolatedStorageSettings Class. You can store data that's specific to the currently signed in user since "ApplicationSettings are stored as per-application, per-computer, and per-user settings."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.105).aspx