# How to save song/mp3 to Media Library in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: mp3, windows-phone-8, media-library

I'm solving simple task - in Windows Phone 8 it should be possible to save mp3 file downloaded from Internet into phone Media Library, not just into Isolated storage. Hint for the API is here:
[What's new in Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Media)
The only thread about this problem I have found:
[MediaLibrary SaveSong method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/f5fa73da-176b-4aaa-8960-8f704236bda5)

Is anywhere simple guide how to **save mp3 song into phone Media Library** or at least **MSDN article** describing the MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go @ [API to add playlists in Zune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385834/api-to-add-playlists-in-zune/14117264#14117264)

Please leave a comment if you've got any additional questions.

Comment: That looks good, thanks! Another question, is it possible to edit information of existing songs in MediaLibrary, for instance creating app for filling missing ID3 Tags of existing songs, including missing album art?

Comment: I don't see how you would do that with this API.