# How to save a song to Music+Video Hub?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

How can I save a song to `Music+Video Hub`?

I know how to get songs:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
var songs = library.Songs;
```

and also how to add a music to new list:

```
MediaHistory.Instance.WriteAcquiredItem(mediaHistoryItem);
```

But How can I add the actual file to `Music + video Hub` so the user can play it like other songs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [API to add playlists in Zune](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385834/api-to-add-playlists-in-zune)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution:
http://abundantcode.com/how-to-copy-a-song-to-windows-phone-music-hublibrary-using-c/
It should help